# Query to assign max date among child items to parent item

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I've data in two Postgres tables as below

table1

```
wid w.name  owner 
1    abc     own1 
2    def     own2 
3    ghi      own3
```

table2

```
vid wid vname date 
9    1   vnam1  10-7-2020
10   1   vnam1  10-8-2018
11   1   vnam2   10-9-2019
12   1   vnam2   10-8-2020
13   2   vnam3  10-10-2017
14   2   vnam3  10-08-2020
15   2   vnam4  10-10-2018
16   2   vnam4  10-10-2019
17   3   vnam5  10-06-2016
18   3   vnam5  10-07-2020
19   3   vnam6  10-08-2020
```

I was able to get max date for each of the table2 vname related to w.name in table2 but I'm looking for something like this in the result so that I can decide each w.name max date.

```
wid w.name owner vname maxdate 
1    abc    own1 vnam2 10-08-2020  (Max date out of 4 values of vnames) <br>
2    def    own2  vnam3 10-08-2020 
3    ghi    own3  vnam6 10-08-2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) to achieve this.

```
select distinct on (t1.wid)
       t1.wid, t1."w.name", t1.owner, t2.vname, t2.date
  from table1 t1
       join table2 t2 on t2.wid = t1.wid
 order by t1.wid, t2.date desc;
```

[Working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6opXrtd9muc9RvZCj938NS/0)